# How to create a proper zip() in python

Tags: python, list, datetime, dictionary, zip

This is my list:

```
mylist = [
        {"size": "XS", "hight": "0.53", "date": "2018-01-01"},
        {"size": "XS", "hight": "0.63", "date": "2018-02-01"},
        {"size": "XS", "hight": "0.73", "date": "2018-03-01"},
        {"size": "XS", "hight": "0.83", "date": "2018-04-01"},
        {"size": "XS", "hight": "0.93", "date": "2018-05-01"},
        {"size": "X", "hight": "1.03", "date": "2018-01-01"},
        {"size": "X", "hight": "1.13", "date": "2018-02-01"},
        {"size": "X", "hight": "1.23", "date": "2018-03-01"},
        {"size": "X", "hight": "1.33", "date": "2018-04-01"},
        {"size": "X", "hight": "1.42", "date": "2018-05-01"},
        {"size": "XL", "hight": "1.52", "date": "2018-01-01"},
        {"size": "XL", "hight": "1.64", "date": "2018-02-01"},
        {"size": "XL", "hight": "1.7", "date": "2018-03-01"},
        {"size": "XL", "hight": "1.8", "date": "2018-04-01"},
        {"size": "XL", "hight": "1.9", "date": "2018-05-01"}]
```

I am going to group by every two json lines. So I have tried this:

```
zip(mylist, mylist[1:]+[mylist[0]])
```

But there is a problem in this way. The last zipped lines would be like:

```
({"size": "XL", "hight": "1.9", "date": "2018-05-01"}, {"size": "XS", "hight": "0.53", "date": "2018-01-01")
```

So in this way I will lose the last interval, so I just tried to add a condition:

```
for first, second in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]+[mylist[0]]):
    first_datetime = datetime.strptime(first['date'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    second_datetime = datetime.strptime(second['date'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    if first == mylist[-1]:
        second_datetime = datetime.now().date()
```

I expect something like:

```
[{'size': 'XS', 'hight': '0.53', 'date': '2018-01-01'}, {'size': 'XS', 'hight': '0.63', 'date': '2018-02-01'}]
[{'size': 'XS', 'hight': '0.63', 'date': '2018-02-01'}, {'size': 'XS', 'hight': '0.73', 'date': '2018-03-01'}]
[{'size': 'XS', 'hight': '0.73', 'date': '2018-03-01'}, {'size': 'XS', 'hight': '0.83', 'date': '2018-04-01'}]
[{'size': 'XS', 'hight': '0.83', 'date': '2018-04-01'}, {'size': 'XS', 'hight': '0.93', 'date': '2018-05-01'}]
[{'size': 'XS', 'hight': '0.93', 'date': '2018-05-01'}, {'size': 'X', 'hight': '1.03', 'date': '2018-01-01'}]
[{'size': 'X', 'hight': '1.03', 'date': '2018-01-01'}, {'size': 'X', 'hight': '1.13', 'date': '2018-02-01'}]
[{'size': 'X', 'hight': '1.13', 'date': '2018-02-01'}, {'size': 'X', 'hight': '1.23', 'date': '2018-03-01'}]
[{'size': 'X', 'hight': '1.23', 'date': '2018-03-01'}, {'size': 'X', 'hight': '1.33', 'date': '2018-04-01'}]
[{'size': 'X', 'hight': '1.33', 'date': '2018-04-01'}, {'size': 'X', 'hight': '1.42', 'date': '2018-05-01'}]
[{'size': 'X', 'hight': '1.42', 'date': '2018-05-01'}, {'size': 'XL', 'hight': '1.52', 'date': '2018-01-01'}]
[{'size': 'XL', 'hight': '1.52', 'date': '2018-01-01'}, {'size': 'XL', 'hight': '1.64', 'date': '2018-02-01'}]
[{'size': 'XL', 'hight': '1.64', 'date': '2018-02-01'}, {'size': 'XL', 'hight': '1.7', 'date': '2018-03-01'}]
[{'size': 'XL', 'hight': '1.7', 'date': '2018-03-01'}, {'size': 'XL', 'hight': '1.8', 'date': '2018-04-01'}]
[{'size': 'XL', 'hight': '1.8', 'date': '2018-04-01'}, {'size': 'XL', 'hight': '1.9', 'date': '2018-05-01'}]
[{'size': 'XL', 'hight': '1.9', 'date': '2018-05-01'}, {'size': 'XS', 'hight': '0.53', 'date': '2018-06-01'}]
```

Is there any smarter way to consider that condition in the zip() at the beginning, something like adding the difference of other periods to the last time?

Comment: What is your desired result for the last line exactly?

Comment: Please add full expected output

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to compute time intervals between events.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> def interval(a, b):
...     return datetime.strptime(b, '%Y-%m-%d').date() - datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Let's try your version:

```
>>> [interval(f['date'], s['date']) for f, s in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]+[mylist[0]])]
[datetime.timedelta(days=31), datetime.timedelta(days=28), ..., datetime.timedelta(days=-120)]
```

The last interval is obviously wrong, because you compare the date of the first event to the date of the last event ("2018-01-01" - "2018-05-01"). You have two solutions: ignore the last interval or add a boundary event.

If you ignore the last event, just remove `+[mylist[0]` (`zip` will stop when `mylist[1:]` is exhasuted):

```
>>> [interval(f['date'], s['date']) for f, s in zip(mylist, mylist[1:])]
[datetime.timedelta(days=31), datetime.timedelta(days=28), ..., datetime.timedelta(days=30)]
```

If you add a boundary event, you'll get a last interval:

```
>>> boundary = {'date': datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')}
>>> [interval(f['date'], s['date']) for f, s in zip(mylist, mylist[1:] + [boundary])]
[datetime.timedelta(days=31), datetime.timedelta(days=28), ..., datetime.timedelta(days=30), datetime.timedelta(days=587)]
```